# How to join taxonomies to a custom table

Tags: drupal, taxonomy

I'm trying to join my content table 'node_field_data' with a custom field table 'node__field_reference_type' and I can't find the taxonomy table that refers to both of them.

Im using Drupal 8.5.4 and mysql for my database.

```
node__field_reference_type
+---------+------------+--------------------------------+
| bundle  | entity_id  | field_reference_type_target_id |
+---------+------------+--------------------------------+
| test    | 10916      | 71                             |
+---------+------------+--------------------------------+

node_field_data
+-------+-------+------+----------------------+
| nid   | vid   | type | title                |
+-------+-------+------+----------------------+
| 10916 | 10905 | test | This is a post title |
+-------+-------+------+----------------------+
```

I don't know what 'field_reference_type_target_id' refers to

Answer (score 0):

I am going on a limb here and assuming that you are trying to get the taxonomy value for the field. **field_reference_type_target_id** refers to the taxonomy Id.
So to get the taxonomy term value do the following:

```
SELECT ttfd.name FROM node_field_data AS nfd 
JOIN node__field_legacy_category AS nflc ON nfd.nid = nflc.entity_id
JOIN taxonomy_term_field_data AS ttfd ON ttfd.tid = 
 nflc.field_legacy_category_target_id
where type = '' and nid = '12345'
```